# Processing wikipedia dump file

Tags: java

I want to process wikipedia dump file. In other meaning i want to extract title , category and text content for each article. what i want to ask about it is there any java api/tool that can help me in doing that.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

The Wikipedia dump file is in XML format. Therefore, you can use any available XML tools for this purpose.

Note that due to the size of the dump file, a SAX parser will generally be much more efficient than a DOM parser (since a DOM parser will try to load the entire thing into a memory representation).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/
Its a java api that gives you structured access to wikipedia dumps, you need a database (mysql or similar) and for recent wikipedia dumps a lot of ram, at least 4g to process though.

But its nice to use:
you can get a iterator over all pages or page titles and a lot more easy to use stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/wiki/MediaWikiDumpSupport

The page has examples of how to work the API.